# How can i set up Download Button that download an apk via Link?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How can i set up Download Button that download an apk via Google Drive Link?

### Sample Code MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.project;
public class VersionActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? 'cause it looks like you expect us to write the code for you witout any contribution from your side

Comment: This is what i tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### @JustSightseeing my complete code

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class VersionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button download;
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_version);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){

                Log.d("permission","permission denied to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - requesting it");
                String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                requestPermissions(permissions,1);
            }


        }

        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {

                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie",cookies);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent",userAgent);
                request.setDescription("Downloading file....");
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimeType));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Downloading File",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```